# Ошибка near ")": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite3

```
page_id = '1'

def checkpage(uid):
    cur.execute(f"SELECT page FROM users WHERE uid = {message.chat.id}")
    return cur.fetchone()
page_id = str(checkpage(message.chat.id))

try:
    cur.execute(f"SELECT image, product_price FROM prise WHERE id = {page_id}")   
    image, product_price = cur.fetchone()
    print(f'{image} - {product_price}')
except Exception as e:
        print('Ошибка: ' + str(e))
```

При запуске выводит Ошибку: *near ")": syntax error*
Пробовал перенести page_id за кавычки

```
cur.execute("SELECT image, product_price FROM prise WHERE id=?", page_id)
```

В таком случае выводит Ошибку: *Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.*

Comment: Для начала  Вы передаёте в checkpage(uid) uid - не используете в функции - вместо message.chat.id надо видимо uid?

Comment: "При запуске выводит Ошибку: near ")": syntax error" - для какой строки?
Может надо для , "page_id)" использовать ", [page_id])" ? не помню точно...

Comment: Вторым аргументом функции execute должен быть кортеж, а вы передали явно не кортеж